# What is the worst case running time in Big-Oh notation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the worst case running time in Big-Oh notation for the function below?Can someone please explain why? Thanks.

```
test{
int counter = 0;

    for int(i=0; i<5000;++i){
    counter += i;
    
        for(j=0;j<n;++j){
        ...
        }
    
        for(k=0;k<i;++k){
        ...
        }
    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

5000 is a constant, so it is not important. The only important thing is the for loop with n in it, so this is O(n).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Big-O notation tells you that the algorythm scales the same or slower then the function.

- O(N) means that if you have 10 times more input data it will take 10 times longer or less.
- O(N^2) means at 10 times more data its 100 times longer or less.

Your input is `n`, `i` is on a costant loop. Therefore your complexity is O(n) as `n` is in a for loop, so it scales linearly, unless you use `n` in another loop somewhere.

You might have noticed the "or less", you might argue that all O(N) algorythms therefore are also O(N^2) or worse, and this is technically true, however not helpful. This is why you'd pick the fastest Big-O notation to indicate a good approximation.

Comment: Got it. Since Big-O is the upper bound, the function is also O(n^2), but it's meaningful because the answer should be the closest time complexity of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Big-O notation talks about the running time *proportional* to n. Here, all loops repeat the same number of times except for one loop with n inside. Therefore, only the inner loops running time changes when n changes, so it is O(n).